# "Featured on Meta" posts are displayed in what order?

Tags: support, sorting, featured-tag

As I am aware [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts are displayed in the "Featured on Meta" in the sidebar. The order of the posts is different on Meta Stack Exchange and other sites.

In what order (post created date, last active date, ...) are the posts displayed in the featured box?

**On Meta Stack Exchange:**

> [image: MSE]

**On Stack Overflow:**

> [image: SO]

Comment: @Glorfindel My question is, on MSE and SO for the same featured question the display order is different. In the linked question, I didn't see any related information.